# How to plot points specified by ID column only with linespoints and multiple plots using gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

Say I have two files, each has 3 columns
file1:

```
ID X Y  
10 0.1 some data as X  
20 0.2  
30 0.3  
... ...  
120 0.5
```

file2:

```
ID    X    Y  
15   0.1   some data as X  
30   0.2  
45   0.3  
60   0.4  
...  ...  
120  0.6
```

I am doing

```
plot \  
"file1" using 2:3 w linespoints lt 1 dt 1 lw 1 lc 1 title "file1",\  
"file2" using 2:3 w linespoints lt 1 dt 1 lw 1 lc 2 title "file2"
```

which shows every point on the file.

If I only want points which its Row ID(first column) is 30, 60 ,90 ,120
How should I do? Thank you.

*In the actually case, I need to plot 12 file in one plot and each of them have 10000 rows but I only want to show 6 points.

Comment: Problem solved? Any feedback would be polite and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your data with the ternary operator. Check `help ternary`.
For the filename and the filter I would define a function such that you have it compact in your plot command.
What `myFilter(dcol,fcol)` does is returning the value of the data column `dcol` if the filter column `fcol` is equal to one of the given values.
`myFilename(n)` creates the filename as a function of a number.

I don't have test files but the following should plot the 12 files names "file1.dat", ..., "file12.dat".
I hope you can adapt it to your exact needs.

**Code:**

```
### filter data with ternary operator
reset session

myFilename(n) = sprintf("file%d.dat",n)

myFilter(dcol,fcol) = column(fcol)==30 || column(fcol)==60 || \
                      column(fcol)==90 || column(fcol)==120 ?  column(dcol) : NaN

set datafile missing NaN

plot for [i=1:12] myFileName(i) u 2:(myFilter(3,1)) w lp ti myFilename(i)
### end of code
```